# error : argument "x" is missing, with no default?

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, r-caret, mlr

As im very new to XGBoost, I am trying to tune the parameters using **mlr** library and model but after using setHayperPars() learning using train() throws an error (in particular when i run **xgmodel** line): **Error in colnames(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default**, and i can't recognize what's this error means, below is the code:

```
library(mlr)     
library(dplyr)
library(caret) 
library(xgboost)

set.seed(12345)
n=dim(mydata)[1]
id=sample(1:n, floor(n*0.6)) 
train=mydata[id,]
test=mydata[-id,]

traintask = makeClassifTask (data = train,target = "label")
testtask = makeClassifTask (data = test,target = "label")

#create learner
lrn = makeLearner("classif.xgboost",
                   predict.type = "response")

lrn$par.vals = list( objective="multi:softprob",
                      eval_metric="merror")

#set parameter space
params = makeParamSet( makeIntegerParam("max_depth",lower = 3L,upper = 10L),
                       makeIntegerParam("nrounds",lower = 20L,upper = 100L),
                       makeNumericParam("eta",lower = 0.1, upper = 0.3),
                       makeNumericParam("min_child_weight",lower = 1L,upper = 10L), 
                       makeNumericParam("subsample",lower = 0.5,upper = 1), 
                       makeNumericParam("colsample_bytree",lower = 0.5,upper = 1)) 


#set resampling strategy

configureMlr(show.learner.output = FALSE, show.info = FALSE)

rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV",stratify = T,iters=5L)

# set the search optimization strategy

ctrl = makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)

# parameter tuning

set.seed(12345)

mytune = tuneParams(learner = lrn, task = traintask, 
                    resampling = rdesc, measures = acc, 
                    par.set = params, control = ctrl,
                    show.info = FALSE)


# build model using the tuned paramters 

#set hyperparameters
lrn_tune = setHyperPars(lrn,par.vals = mytune$x)

#train model
xgmodel = train(learner = lrn_tune,task = traintask)
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be *very* careful when loading multiple packages that may involve methods with the same name - here `caret` and `mlr`, which both include a `train` method. Moreover, the *order* of the `library` statements is significant: here, as `caret` is loaded after `mlr`, it masks functions with the same name from it (and possibly every other package loaded previously), like `train`.

In your case, where you obviously want to use the `train` method from `mlr` (and not from `caret`), you should declare this explicitly in your code:

```
xgmodel = mlr::train(learner = lrn_tune,task = traintask)
```